# How to insert index, values of list into a dictionary values(based on length of the other list)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

I have two lists`(l,s)`. Now I want to create a dictionary where I want to add the index values, values of the lists to a dictionary keys that looks like below.

`{"value_s": index value of s, "Name_s": value of list s,'value_l': index value of l, 'value_s': value of list s}`

Suppose list l have four values and s have two values, then based on the length of list l the number of index's should be added to s. If the length of l is 4 then the for loop should add one to four to `value_s` and the `value_l` should be 0 for the first run. This might be confusing for better understanding refer to the code and the excepted output below:-

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
s = ['q','w']
```

The above are the two lists. Now the excepted output is:-

```
[{'value_s': '0', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 0, 'Name_l': 'a'}, 
 {'value_s': '0', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 1, 'Name_l': 'b'}, 
 {'value_s': '0', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 2, 'Name_l': 'c'}, 
 {'value_s': '0', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 3, 'Name_l': 'd'}, 
 {'value_s': '1', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 0, 'Name_l': 'a'}, 
 {'value_s': '1', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 1, 'Name_l': 'b'}, 
 {'value_s': '1', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 2, 'Name_l': 'c'}, 
 {'value_s': '1', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 3, 'Name_l': 'd'}, 
]
```

All though I tried implementing the basic part of inserting the index and values. The idea what I did is not a good way to do

```
f=[]
for idx, val in enumerate(s):
  for index, value in  enumerate(l):
    name = {"value_s":idx, "Name_s": val,'value_l':index, 'value_s':value }
    f.append(name)
```

This gives me:-

```
[{'value_s': 'a', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 0}, 
 {'value_s': 'b', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 1},
 {'value_s': 'c', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 2},
 {'value_s': 'd', 'Name_s': 'q', 'value_l': 3},
 {'value_s': 'a', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 0},
 {'value_s': 'b', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 1},
 {'value_s': 'c', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 2},
 {'value_s': 'd', 'Name_s': 'w', 'value_l': 3}]
```

Is there any good way to achieve the excepted output?

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique. You can't have two keys called "Name_s"

Comment: I think you need to switch your two for statements.  Iterate over l first then over s.  And yes, the last key in name should be value_l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
s = ['q','w']

f=[]
for idx, val in enumerate(l):
  for index, value in  enumerate(s):
    name = { "value_s":index, "Name_s": value, 'value_l':idx, 'name_l':val }
    f.append(name)

print(f)
```